# How can I show with *ngIf only 1 time items of array that have the same value?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

[image]I have a 2d array. Example :

```js
weatherForecast = [
  [Weather(Monday, 10C, 11:00), (Weather(Monday, 12:00)],
  [Weather(Tuesday, 10C, 11:00),(Weather(Tuesday, 12:00)]
];
```

How can I print once the day if the value is the same. Code:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let forecast of weatherForecast; let i = index">
      <ion-col *ngFor="let weatherData of forecast; let j = index">
        <div *ngIf="weatherData[j].day !== forecast[j - 1].day">
          {{ forecast[j].day }}
        </div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let weatherData of forecast; let j = index">
        <div>
          {{ forecast[j].temperature }}
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Please show `weatherForecast` json data

Comment: @AdritaSharma weatherForecast is the table.

Comment: what does dhoe mean?

Comment: I suggest filtering out all unneeded data once in the component code so that you don't have to filter it in the template.

Comment: @IvanKashtanov the problem is that the data is already filtered but how should I again refilter it? please give example.

Comment: @ArchitGarg show

Comment: Add `{{weatherForecast |  json}}` in your html and show the result

Comment: @KathrineHanson it look like you want to skip entries with same temperature, but some of the entries from your example don't have a temperature value. If they actually do in the real app, just make a new array of entries for each day skipping an entry if the previous one has the same temp.

Comment: @KathrineHanson if there're no temp values and it's supposed to be like this, skip entries without temp value during filtering.

Comment: @AdritaSharma see my pic

Comment: @IvanKashtanov no, i do now want to skip temp. I just want to print the day property only once if it is the same. see my pic that I uploaded. for example I have 3 entries that have the same day(20). I want to print it once. how can i do it with *ngIf?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve this, this should work,

```
let aux;
let filterForecast = [];
for (let i = 0; i < weatherForecast.length; i++) {
  aux = {};
  for (let j = 0; j < weatherForecast[i].length; j++) {
    if (!aux.hasOwnProperty(weatherForecast[i][j].day)) {
      aux[weatherForecast[i][j].day] = weatherForecast[i][j];
    }
  }
  filterForecast.push(Object.values(aux));
}
```

I use a pretty simple code, you will have to adapt it to your code. This approach resolves the problem in the code instead of the template. I just use a dictionary to keep the different days, and then just add to the result the values of the dictionary. With this you will have to use 
`filterForecast` instead of `weatherForecast` in the template.

Assuming that the inner array is ordered by day, then just using `*ngIf`,

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let forecast of weatherForecast; let i = index">
      <ion-col *ngFor="let weatherData of forecast; let j = index">
        <div *ngIf="j === 0 || weatherData.day !== forecast[j - 1].day">
          {{ weatherData.day }}
        </div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let weatherData of forecast; let j = index">
        <!-- I am not sure if you need to check here too -->
        <div>
          {{ weatherData.temperature }}
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. Firstly, u need to add .length in the for loop. And it does not work, it prints aux is not a function. The last line has a problem.

Comment: You are correct, I have edit the mistakes. Sorry about that.

Comment: sorry again but it does not work. it is filled with 0 elements. however, I again have a 2d array. so there is no difference and not solving my pro with *ngIf.

Comment: the if condition had a mistake, is "if does not have the day", i miss the not  `!`, that cause the empty result .. check again

Comment: I think that if you want to solve it using just using `*ngIf`, the inner array must be sorted by day, then I think your code could work, although you will have to check also for the temperature